# Having trouble using a if boolean statement to redirect in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

I may be going about this completely wrong

what I was wanting to do is something along the lines of the code below where when_appointment is a boolean.

```
def create
  @visit = Visit.create(visit_params)
  if visit.when_appointment == "true"
    redirect_to new_appointment_path
  else
    redirect_to new_chat_path, :notice => "User updated."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby:

```
true == 'true'
# => false
```

and Rails type-cast attributes upon assignment, so if you have:

```
visit_params[:when_appointment]
# => "true"
```

or

```
visit_params[:when_appointment]
# => "1"
```

you would have:

```
visit = Visit.new(visit_params)
visit.when_appointment
# => true
```

So, returning to your question, you should have:

```
if visit.when_appointment
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

Comment: It's important to note that Rails type-casts attributes upon assignment, i.e. `Visit.create(when_appointment: "true")` sets `when_appointment` to `true` (assuming this is a boolean field).